# Why does the generated .NET proxy for this WSDL drop some data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, soap, wsdl

I've added a WCF service reference to a .NET project using this WSDL:
https://interop.cmiservices.org/axis/services/CAP1_1?wsdl

It generates the proxy classes, etc., and I am able to call the methods.  However, when calling 'getCAPAlerts', or 'getCAPAlert', the return values seem to be missing data.  For example, 'getCAPAlert' returns an 'alert' instance, but it's 'info' property is always null. Using Fiddler, I can examine the XML and see that an  element is returned from the server (see below). One possibly related note: 'info' is defined as 0..unbounded on 'alert' in the wsdl, and an array is generated in the proxy.  Also, the behavior is the same with .net 2.0-style web reference using WSE3.

As a workaround, I have written classes that do their own XML serialization (ie implement IXmlSerializable), and these do deserialize as expected (ie info != null).  However, hand-coding these is error-prone and has some other drawbacks.

Why would the generated proxy classes not deserialize properly?  What is the best way to go about correcting this?

SOAP response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Header>
    <ns1:serverTime soapenv:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next" soapenv:mustUnderstand="0" xmlns:ns1="http://dmi-services.org/CAP/1.0"></ns1:serverTime>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
    <ns2:getCAPAlertResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns2="http://dmi-services.org">
        <getCAPAlertReturn>
            <identifier>EINC171254539121009-6228</identifier>
            <sender>dmis@cmiservices.org</sender>
            <sent>2009-12-10T17:12:05</sent>
            <status>Test</status>
            <msgType>Alert</msgType>
            <source xsi:nil="true"/>
            <scope>Private</scope>
            <restriction xsi:nil="true"/>
            <addresses xsi:nil="true"/>
            <code></code>
            <note xsi:nil="true"/>
            <references xsi:nil="true"/>
            <incidents xsi:nil="true"/>
            <info>
                <language xsi:nil="true"/>
                <category>Other</category>
                <event>TEST TEST TEST Automobile Accident</event>
                <urgency>Past</urgency>
                <severity>Minor</severity>
                <certainty>Unlikely</certainty>
                <audience xsi:nil="true"/>
                <effective xsi:nil="true"/>
                <onset xsi:nil="true"/>
                <expires xsi:nil="true"/>
                <senderName>Customer Name</senderName>
                <headline>TEST TEST FROM ETEAM INCIDENT</headline>
                <description>desctiption</description>
                <instruction xsi:nil="true"/>
                <web xsi:nil="true"/>
                <contact xsi:nil="true"/>
            </info>
        </getCAPAlertReturn>
    </ns2:getCAPAlertResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Generated 'alert' proxy class:

```
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "2.0.50727.4927")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.SoapTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:emergency:cap:1.1")]
public partial class Alert : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private string identifierField;

    private string senderField;

    private string sentField;

    private status statusField;

    private msgType msgTypeField;

    private string sourceField;

    private System.Nullable<scope> scopeField;

    private string restrictionField;

    private string addressesField;

    private string[] codeField;

    private string noteField;

    private string referencesField;

    private string incidentsField;

    private info[] infoField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string identifier {
        get {
            return this.identifierField;
        }
        set {
            this.identifierField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("identifier");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string sender {
        get {
            return this.senderField;
        }
        set {
            this.senderField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("sender");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string sent {
        get {
            return this.sentField;
        }
        set {
            this.sentField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("sent");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public status status {
        get {
            return this.statusField;
        }
        set {
            this.statusField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("status");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public msgType msgType {
        get {
            return this.msgTypeField;
        }
        set {
            this.msgTypeField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("msgType");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public string source {
        get {
            return this.sourceField;
        }
        set {
            this.sourceField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("source");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public System.Nullable<scope> scope {
        get {
            return this.scopeField;
        }
        set {
            this.scopeField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("scope");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public string restriction {
        get {
            return this.restrictionField;
        }
        set {
            this.restrictionField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("restriction");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public string addresses {
        get {
            return this.addressesField;
        }
        set {
            this.addressesField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("addresses");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public string[] code {
        get {
            return this.codeField;
        }
        set {
            this.codeField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("code");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public string note {
        get {
            return this.noteField;
        }
        set {
            this.noteField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("note");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public string references {
        get {
            return this.referencesField;
        }
        set {
            this.referencesField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("references");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public string incidents {
        get {
            return this.incidentsField;
        }
        set {
            this.incidentsField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("incidents");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>        
    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public info[] info {
        get {
            return this.infoField;
        }
        set {
            this.infoField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("info");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `info` property returns an array of `info` objects.  Is the `info` object/class serializable?

Comment: Is the webservice yours, such that you can adjust the wsdl xsd schema?

Comment: Sorry for abandoning this post.  Info was also generated by the wsdl tool, and unfortunately, no, this is not a service we control.  Pats right, this source did not correctly implement a spec. Also, the .net serialize has problems with 0..* elements...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DMIS did not implement the alert object correctly.

Their version uses a capital A `<Alert>` while the oasis defines it as `<alert>`

Also there are issues with the namespaces, you need to make sure the proper namespaces are included for deserialization.